# Error 500 ZF2 curl adapter

Tags: curl, zend-framework2

I recieve an 500 error when I call the curl adapter:

```
$client->setAdapter(new \Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl());
```

I use ZF2 version 2.3 and I am calling this from a controller action.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Show your controller's action related code

Comment: cURL installed? Check your error log, it will contain the actual error message.

Comment: fixed! Error related due a bad instalation of cURL